# Как сделать так, чтобы у пользователей сайта "A" незаметно для них устанавливались куки с сайта "B"?

Tags: php, cookie, безопасность

Как сделать так, чтобы у пользователей сайта "A" незаметно для них устанавливались куки с сайта "B"?

На сайтах, которые не запрещают показывать себя в iframe, это решается загрузкой страницы сайта "B" в невидимый фрейм. Вместе со страницей прилетают и куки.

Но есть сайты, которые запрещают показывать себя в фреймах и переадресовывают на себя любимых.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что и как делать в таких случаях? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открывать JS [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) новое окно с сайтом B: без меню, минимального размера, под остальными окнами. Поскольку окно открыто скриптом из сайта A, он же сможет его самостоятельно закрыть: через 10 секунд, например.

Comment: 1) Настройки: Блокировать всплывающие окна.  2) Минимальный размер всплывающего окна 100х100 пкс

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
<img src="http://hashcode.ru/" alt="" />
```

Comment: C hashcode.ru куки прилетают, а с того сайта, который нужен - нет. :(

Comment: Значит хороший сайт. А вы XSS пишете?

Comment: Нет. Просто экспериментирую. :) Сайт "А" может показывать своим пользователям определённую информацию, только если эти пользователи уже были на сайте "B" и получали от него куки. :)